# Sample integration test with Flutter new integration_test?

Tags: flutter, dart, integration-testing, flutterdriver

Sample integration test  with Flutter new [integration_test](https://pub.dev/packages/integration_test) ?

Answer (score 5):

1. First add a dependency in pubspec.yaml under dev

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  test: ^1.9.4
```

2. Your package should have a structure that looks like this:
   [image]
3. in test/test_driver/integration_test.dart

   ```
                  import'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver.dart';

                                  Future<void> main() => integrationDriver();
   ```

4.In integration_test/foo_test.dart
example

```
                                    void main() {
                                      IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
                                      testWidgets("Sign in test example", (WidgetTester tester) async {
                                        final Finder signInEmailField = find.byKey(Key('signInEmailField'));
                                        final Finder signInPasswordField = find.byKey(Key('signInPasswordField'));
                                        final Finder signInSaveButton = find.byKey(Key('signInSaveButton'));
  
                                        await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
  
                                        await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  
                                        await tester.tap(find.byKey(Key('signInEmailField')));
                                        await tester.enterText(signInEmailField, "paras@gmail.com");
  
                                        await tester.tap(signInPasswordField);
                                        await tester.enterText(signInPasswordField, "123456");
  
                                        await tester.tap(signInSaveButton);
                                        print("button tapped");
                                        await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 1));
                                        expect(
                                            find.byWidgetPredicate((widget) =>
                                                widget is AppBar &&
                                                widget.title is Text &&
                                                (widget.title as Text).data.startsWith("ToDoApp")),
                                            findsOneWidget);
  
                                        await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 1));
                                      });
                                    }
```

5. Add key like we set in flutter_driver

   ```
                      appBar: AppBar(
                        title: Text(
                          'ToDoApp',
                          key: Key("toDoKey"),
                        ),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
                      ),
   ```
6. Foo last run the command in your terminal
   flutter drive 
   --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart 
   --target=integration_test/foo_test.dart

Thanks.. happy Fluttering

Comment: I have followed your tutorial, it was very helpful, thank you. Have you experienced [my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65528412/3935156) before?

Comment: hi, in 4th step, whats `MyApp()`? is that the view that we want to test or something else?